# How create geographic column in PostGIS table?

Tags: qgis, postgis, merge

I merged several point shapefiles in PostGIS, but when I load the new merged shape in QGIS it is not possible to see points in the main window. To create the merged table I used this piece of code found in the forum:

```
CREATE TABLE merged (id serial primary key, attrib1 integer, attrib2 varchar(15),....);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('merged','geom',<SRID>,'<FEATURE_TYPE>,'XY');
INSERT INTO merged (attrib1, attrib2, ...., geom) SELECT attribA, attribB,...,geom FROM table_1;
INSERT INTO merged (attrib1, attrib2, ...., geom) SELECT attribA, attribB,...,geom FROM table_2;
```

I think that the problem is that in the merged table the geographic column is empty. I tried to populate this column, but my attempt failed.

How can I populate this column?

Comment: What is that XY in AddGeometryColumn ? see http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html

Probably reason why you dont get any data in geom columns , is that AddGeometryColumn add constraint to your table which differs from your data. If i read given code right you add geom colum to merge table with empty SRID and XY type , XY is not suppported type. it should be POINT in this case. Also that XY gives me impressio nthat you have column with x and y values ?

Answer (score 1):

Try query:

```
CREATE TABLE "merged" AS
SELECT geom, attrib1, attrib2 FROM "table_1"
UNION
SELECT geom, attrib1, attrib2 FROM "table_2"
```

Comment: Only one problem in this, you don't get that id primary key what QGIS wants. I tried to research is there way add primary key in SELECT INTO clause but no success. Do you have anyideas ? (or if geoms are unique use them as unique id, but still same problem no primary key in table )

Comment: in my work I used query above, it was not necessary in the 'primary key' for the 'union' table. But I don't have idea how add 'primary key':/

Comment: Use `row_number() OVER () AS rowid` in your SELECT clause.

Answer (score 1):

With two queries

```
CREATE TABLE merged (id serial primary key, attrib1 integer, attrib2 varchar(15), geom geometry);
INSERT INTO merged (attrib1, attrib2, geom) 
SELECT l.at1 as attrib1 , l.at2 as attrib2 , l.geom FROM table_1 as l UNION 
SELECT a.at1 as attrib1 , a.at2 as attrib2,  a.geom FROM table_2 as a
```

And I am trying to get it into one query for fun. Closest what I got is this

```
SELECT row_number() over() as gid, res.* INTO merged2 FROM (
    SELECT l.at1 as attrib1 , l.at2 as attrib2 , l.geom FROM table_1 as l UNION 
    SELECT a.at1 as attrib1 , a.at2 as attrib2,  a.geom FROM table_2 as a ) as res
```

Only problem in this "one liner" is that id doesn't specify `gid` as primary key

Answer (score 0):

In your Select AddGemetryColumn(...) statement you're missing the POINT data type and the CRS (epsg id number). So it should be

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('merged','geom',4326,'POINT','XY');
```

(Assuming your data is in lon/lat WGS84 datum)